# Why replace the line break?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

I would like the replace all the spaces in my project.
And my project has many \n.
But when I replace the space, and the \n be replaced at the same time.

For example

```
var s = '1\n'; 
var re = s.replace(/\s/g,"**");
console.log(re); //1**
```

I don't expect this result

Comment: `\s` matches all white-space characters which include Newlines too. Instead of a `\s`, you can use a space in `var re = s.replace(/ /g,"**");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\s` normally matches: space, tab, newline, carriage return, and vertical tab.

I think what you want is `/ |\t/g` (space or tab) rather than `/\s/g`.

If you really want to replace *only* the spaces, use `/ /g`.

Comment: Great, I check it from MDN
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

\s matches a white space character, including space, tab, form feed, line feed. Equivalent to [ \f\n\r\t\v\u00a0\u1680\u2000-\u200a\u2028\u2029\u202f\u205f\u3000\ufeff].

Thanks for your great help.